# Can I integrate jbpm in .net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jbpm, kie-workbench

I am very new to JBPM.
I've a .net MVC based web application to which I need to integrate JBPM.I am not able to find any sample application or tutorial where I can see these details.

Comment: not sure exactly what your requirement or what precisely you mean by "integrate" (it can take many different forms), but I worked on a system for a few years where JBPM was part of the application ecosystem. Interaction between JBPM and the rest of the applications (some web applications, some services) was done by means of webservices which JBPM exposed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate your non-Java application with jBPM, you can use [KIE Server](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e23764). It is a lightweight application with embedded jBPM engine which can be deployed for example on Tomcat. You can then make use of its REST API to run business processes, complete human tasks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but keep in mind that integration is limited - you still have to create process models in kie-workbench.

You can use API for starting and completing a process and getting a variety of informations about process state. You can also extend API by your own functionality. We are working on such integration so feel free to ask me any questions, but please be more specific - at least provide information what for JBPM will be used in your system, and what functionalities you want to integrate.